# Scrape "next page" in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape a web page's next page. They are total 20 pages of this. I want to use first page's url to scrape the next page.

Code:

```
b=[]
url="https://abcde.com/cate6-%E7%BE%8E%E5%A6%9D%E4%BF%9D%E9%A4%8A/"
res=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
b.append(url)
while True:   
    try:
        dct = {"data-icon":"k"}
        url=soup.find('',dct)
        url=(url['href'])
        print(url)
    except TypeError:   
        break
    if url:
        url=("https://abcde.com"+url)
        print(url)  
        b.append(url) 
print(b)
```

next page's HTML:

```
<li class="next"><a href="https://abcde.com/cate6-%E7%BE%8E%E5%A6%9D%E4%BF%9D%E9%A4%8A/?p=2" data-icon="k">next page</a></li>
```

last page's HTML:

```
<li class="next disabled"><a href="" data-icon="k">next page</a></li>
```

It only prints out the first page's url.

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect to happen? You only call `requests.get(url)` once, which is before you enter a `while True` loop. You will need to place `res=requests.get(url)` and all subsequent lines inside of the while-loop so your code actually fetches the subsequent pages. For example:

```
# The following are used for debugging output in this example:
#import sys
#import traceback

# ... Your other code...

b=[]
url="https://abcde.com/cate6-%E7%BE%8E%E5%A6%9D%E4%BF%9D%E9%A4%8A/"
b.append(url)
while True:
    try:
        res=requests.get(url)
    except:
        print("Failed while fetching " + str(url))
        print("Stack trace:")
        traceback.print_exc()
        break;
    # end try
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    except:
        print("Failed setting up beautiful soup parser object.")
        print("Response from request for '" + str(url) + "' was: \n\t" + str(res).replace("\n", "\n\t"), file=sys.stderr) # Avoids polluting STDOUT
        traceback.print_exc()
        break;
    # end try

    # The following line is not needed here because the new URL is added in the IF statement at the bottom of loop:
    # b.append(url)

    try:
        dct = {"data-icon":"k"}
        url=soup.find('',dct)
        url=(url['href'])
        print(url)
    except TypeError:
        print("Leaving loop after Parsing of URL from page failed.")
        break
    if url:
        url=("https://abcde.com"+url)
        print(url)  
        b.append(url)
# end while True

# Debug statement:
print("Outside of loop.")

# Print output
print(b)
```

This requests the page for the new URL every time because the `requests.get(url)` is inside of the loop, causing it to be executed at every iteration.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. You code print out: Leaving loop after Parsing of URL from page failed.
Outside of loop.
['https://abcde.com/cate6-%E7%BE%8E%E5%A6%9D%E4%BF%9D%E9%A4%8A/'] but I think my problem is how to get the url from next page, so probably I got the error from "try" in my code.

Comment: @Makiyo In that case, I would recommend placing a `traceback.print_exc()` in the exception handler that has that print statement. Perhaps `lxml` is an improper choice for parsing the page which is causing the find command to fail? I haven't used Beautiful Soup in years, so my memory on things specific to BS is hazy.